# Trouble with redirect after form submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that uses jQuery and Ajax to help manage multiple file uploads. Everything works fine except for the redirect on success. The script was provided by stack user prateekkathal and looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () //Setting up on Document to Ready Function
{
    $("#btnUpload").click(function (event) {

        //getting form into Jquery Wrapper Instance to enable JQuery Functions on form                    
        var form = $("#inquiry");

        //Serializing all For Input Values (not files!) in an Array Collection so that we can iterate this collection later.
        var params = form.serializeArray();

        //Getting Files Collection
        var files = $("#File1")[0].files;

        //Declaring new Form Data Instance  
        var formData = new FormData();

        //Looping through uploaded files collection in case there is a Multi File Upload. This also works for single i.e simply remove MULTIPLE attribute from file control in HTML.  
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
        }
        //Now Looping the parameters for all form input fields and assigning them as Name Value pairs. 
        $(params).each(function (index, element) {
            formData.append(element.name, element.value);
        });

        //disabling Submit Button so that user cannot press Submit Multiple times
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.val("Uploading...");

        $.ajax({
            url: "relay2.php", //You can replace this with MVC/WebAPI/PHP/Java etc
            method: "post",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
                //Firing event if File Upload is completed!  
                alert("Upload Completed");
                btn.prop("disabled", false);
                btn.val("Submit");
                $("#File1").val("");
                window.location.replace('https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html');
            },
        });
    });
});
```

I am trying to figure out how to redirect the user to a thank you page once the form submits. The script calls the form handler script which is supposed to redirect the user to the thank you page, but I think the `success: function ()` is getting in the way. I am unsure how to edit the success function to redirect the user to the thank you page.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I should note that when I include the path to my form handler in the form action it works as expected, but sends the form data twice. I'm guessing this is because the form handler is being called twice. Once from the action attribute and once from the above script.

Comment: Why use an AJAX call if you want to send the user to another page after form submission? Why not just use a regular html form submission then? The point of using AJAX is to keep them on the same page.

Comment: @jwebb The op has an error case in the ajax. If he just used form post the user will be on the wrong page when an error is present

Comment: @Seth McClaine errors can be handled with an HTML form post too without going to another page.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know that I need to use Ajax. This was the only script that I could find that seems to accomplish what I am trying to do. The end goal is to allow users to upload multiple files via a single input field and have those files attached to the email that gets sent on submit. My form handler script does not support multi file uploads from a single input, so I am trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Ah It sounds like your real problem is not being able to support multiple file uploads from a single input

Comment: @jwebb Agreed. That is the base issue. The above script handles that perfectly except for the redirect.

Comment: @5150 Design Do you need a whole thank you page? Do you have other things on it besides "Thank you"? Another way to go is just a green checkbox and Thank You! appears at the bottom of the form instead of a redirect.

Comment: Thanks @jwebb. I actually solved the problem by adding the thank you URL to the form's action attribute as per Seth McClain's suggestion. Appreciate your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can throw `window.location.href="{path}"` in your success function. You will want this after your alert, as soon as the alert is clicked you will be redirected - this might make everything else youre doing in success a moot point

```
     $.ajax({
            url: "formHandler.php", //You can replace this with MVC/WebAPI/PHP/Java etc
            method: "post",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {
               //Firing event if File Upload is completed!  
                alert("Upload Completed");
                /* you will redirect before the users have a chance to see these actions take effect unless you move them before the alert
                btn.prop("disabled", false); 
                btn.val("Submit");
                $("#File1").val("");
                */
                window.location.href = 'https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html'; 
            },
            error: function (error) { alert("Error"); }
        });
```

Alternatively you could try to submit your form instead

Assuming form is set up as so...

```
<form id="inquiry" action="https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html">


 $.ajax({
        url: "formHandler.php", //You can replace this with MVC/WebAPI/PHP/Java etc
        method: "post",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function () {
           //Firing event if File Upload is completed!  
            alert("Upload Completed");
            /* you will redirect before the users have a chance to see these actions take effect unless you move them before the alert
            btn.prop("disabled", false); 
            btn.val("Submit");
            $("#File1").val("");
            */
            $('#inquiry').submit()
        },
        error: function (error) { alert("Error"); }
    });
```

Comment: McClain Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, window.location does not work. It simply reloads the current page. Also tried window.location.href and window.location.replace to no avail.

Comment: you will need to give a qualified path such as `//stackoverflow.com` or fully qualified such as `https://stackoverflow.com`

Comment: I did use an absolute URL like this: window.location = '{https://pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html}';. In fact, now I do not even receive an email with the  form data.

Comment: `window.location='https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html'` or 
`window.location='//www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html'`

Comment: try `window.location.href = 'https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html'` and lmk if that doesn't work

Comment: Another things to try is `window.location.replace('https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html');`

Comment: I've tried both. Updated my question to reflect the changes.

Comment: does your form have an action on it? You could try `$('#inquiry').submit()`. (`<form id="inquiry" action="https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html">`). Not sure if that will make a difference though...

Comment: That worked! You are awesome! Post it as an answer so I can mark it as 'the answer'. Thanks for your time and expertise.

Comment: It should be `window.location.href = 'https://www.pmd-fla.com/thankyou2.html'`. What about taking out the alert? Do you need it if you're sending people to a thank you page?

Comment: Modified the current answer with an alternative

Comment: @Seth Modified answer does not send files? It works well without the */
     $('#inquiry').submit() and putting the thnk you url in the action attribute. Although it starts the upload process before 'required' fields are verified, so if the user goes back and fills required fields then clicks 'submit' again, I get two submissions. Thanks again for your help! Please edit your answer so as not to confuse others - I marked it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that you could use is submitting the form via an iframe. This way the user would still be on the same page.

You would need to add and iframe:

```
<iframe name="ifrm_submit" id="ifrm_submit" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

Once you have this iframe in place, you need to change how your form submits the data. You can do this by adding a target attribute to the form element.

```
<form target="ifrm_submit" method="post" action="formHandler.php">
    <!-- I assume that your multiple file inputs are part of this form -->
</form>
```

You also need to add a javascript function which would be able to repsond to  the form submission callback.

```
function fileUploaded(resp){
    if(resp.error == 0){
        window.location.href=resp.redirect_url;
    }else{
        alert(resp.message); //assuming there was an error and a message was set for the same
    }
}
```

In the php script that handles the file upload you can create some json data and then echo that into the iframe.

```
<?php
//handle file upload, validation, etc.
$resp_data = [
    'error' => 0, //assuming there were no errors while uploading
    'redirect_url' => 'http://someurl.com'
    ];
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.parent.fileUploaded('.json_encode($resp_data).'); </script>';
die();
?>
```

Here is how it works:

1. The form is submitted via the iframe
2. PHP output is sent to the iframe
3. The javascript code in iframe gets invoked and it calls the parent pages javascript function
4. The parent pages javascript handles the response received.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually solved it as per Seth McClain's suggestion by adding the thank you page to the form's action attribute.

Comment: Why you should avoid iframes: https://www.ostraining.com/blog/webdesign/against-using-iframes/

Comment: That was just a suggestion my friend on how you could do file uploads and still be on the same page. I totally agree with the success handler approach if you are using ajax. I still do not agree fully with #1 on the suggested link as that iframe loads my websites page and not any 3rd party website. The OP did mention that he/she was not sure if ajax was even needed.